# google デベロッパーツール

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

MuiFormControl-rootとMuiFormControl-marginNormalとcss-ufpu9p-MuiFormControl-root
画像右上の青いdivに適用されてます。
でも画像右下でMuiFormControl-rootとMuiFormControl-marginNormalが表示されません。
何故でしょう？

[image: google デベロッパーツール]

Comment: HTMLやCSSに依存する話なので、それらの全体を質問に含められませんか?